# Creating a new database with oracle dbca (oracle database configuration assistant)

Tags: oracle

I will creating a new database which I will add it new tables. I'm using Oracle Database Express 11g r2 edition. I searched on Google how creating a new database. They are using Oracle DBCA, but can't find this tool on my PC under oracle tools.

How can I open this Oracle DBCA?

Comment: AFAIK Oracle Express only allows a single database. But more than one database is very rarely needed anyway. Are you sure you don't simply want a new schema (if you are coming from MySQL/SQL Server: a database there is almost always mapped to a schema/user in Oracle)

Comment: You says if I use oracle express edition,I can't create a new database , I can use only one database wich is created on installing ,isn't it?

Comment: I'm saying: you don't need a second database (and in your case you can't create a second one anyway). Use the one that got created during installation. If you need separate "namespaces" create a new schema/user.

Comment: You might want to read this: http://dba.stackexchange.com/a/35912/1822

Comment: you want tool to work with oracle?